# Best way to run batch file in network drive in Windows Sever through SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I am currently using SSH to connect to a Window Server with freeSSHd to run batch files.

If the batch file is in C drive, then using my command works:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' server -l name 'C:\test.bat'
```

However, if my batch file is in a non-C drive, then it would say: The system cannot find the drive specified. For example:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\ssh.exe -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' server -l name 'W:\test.bat'
```

How would I run a batch file in network drive through SSH then?

Also what is the way to check if W:\test.bat file exist?

Answer (score 1):

You should first change the current directory with this command

```
w:
```

then you should be able to run the script. Anyway, a few months ago I was running in the same issue and ended up making a super simple PHP local only script to run my bat. I think is the best way if you already have a PHP server on it